# Azure storage queue emits incorrect metric

Tags: azure-storage, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I'm using Queue trigger [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to process storage queue messages. The queue messages are processed quickly and I don't see any failures in Azure functions logs. However, the storage queue is showing incorrect metrics for the active message count over a duration of 3 hours. This looks like incorrect metric reporting and creates false alarm. Any reason for this ?

[image]